# exact documentation for clock sync on GCC VM's?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I've spent a lot of time searching, but haven't found any concrete (i.e. something I can give to a customer) details on GCC VM clock synchronization. My RHEL Vm's don't have ntp running, but I found a blog page that said the system clock in a VM is automatically synched - but can't find this in the actual GCC docs.

Is it in fact OK to not run ntp, or should I turn it on? If the answer is it's not needed, is there any place where this is definitively stated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instances#configure-ntp) Compute Engine instances are preconfigured to use network time protocol (NTP). Also [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/internal-dns#internal_dns_and_resolvconf) describes that Compute Engine instances are configured to renew DHCP leases every 24 hours.

In GCE Debian VMs, the `ntp` script can be found at `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-exit-hooks.d/` directory and in GCE Red Hat and CentOS VMs `ntp.sh` script is located at `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/` . The ntp script runs during DHCP renewal and synchronize time with NTP server: `169.254.169.254`.